# SQL Order by the number at the end of the string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with some columns and I want to order the selection by the column 'post_id'. The rows are like this: 'rgpost0', 'rgpost1','rcpost2', ...

How can I order the selection by the number at the end of the value of the column 'post_id' descending?

This code is not working: `SELECT * FROM posts_info ORDER BY post_id+0 DESC`

**I don't want to change the column type to number. I just want to order by number at the end of the string.**

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`reverse()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) twice:

```
SELECT * FROM posts_info 
ORDER BY reverse(reverse(post_id) + 0) + 0 DESC
```

For this table:

```
create table posts_info(id int, post_id varchar(100));
insert into posts_info(id, post_id) values
(1, 'bob52'),
(2, 'alice634'),
(3, 'john12'),
(4, 'mark7'),
(5, 'mary001');
```

Results:

```
| id  | post_id  |
| --- | -------- |
| 2   | alice634 |
| 1   | bob52    |
| 3   | john12   |
| 4   | mark7    |
| 5   | mary001  |
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5UawMtH8DUY27fD79bTfzu/0).

Comment: Nevertheless it does work for the sample data given, and is creative +1.

Comment: @H.Farid this answer is good but not sure it you should do this on runtime all the time without some optimisation... So for MySQL  's  8.0.13+ [functional/expressional index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts).. For lower MySQL versions 5.7+ untill MySQL 8.0.12 you can simulate it with [generated columns which are indexable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), if you already have a table you offcource need to use ALTER to add that generated column..

Comment: This is wrong. This doesn't work for 10 (reverse of the ten is 01=1 and 100 --> 001=1 and...).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MySQL 8+ then we can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts_info
ORDER BY
    CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(post_id, '[0-9]+$') AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    post_id DESC;
```

I added a second sorting level in case two `post_id` happen to end in the same number.  In this case, I order descending by the entire `post_id`.

Comment: How can I check MySQL version? (im using mysqli with php)

Comment: You can try just using my code.  If `REGEXP_SUBSTR` gives you an error, then your version might not support it.

Comment: Thanks but no need to the second sorting level, because the 'post_id' is unique!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM posts_info ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(post_id, 7) AS UNSIGNED) DESC;
```